# Why does this Java NaCl encryption not work with GitHub Actions Secrets

Tags: python, java, encryption, groovy

I'm attempting to write a Java app that creates secrets in a GitHub repo to be consumed by GitHub Actions. There are many SodiumLib wrappers available, but they generally wrap up the native C library. I was looking for a pure Java implementation.

https://github.com/NeilMadden/salty-coffee appears to be what I need, and it does appear that the library will create encrypted string. The Groovy script below takes a key and input value, and generates an encrypted value:

```
@Grab(group='software.pando.crypto', module='salty-coffee', version='1.0.4')
@Grab(group='org.apache.commons', module='commons-lang3', version='3.12.0')
@Grab(group='commons-codec', module='commons-codec', version='1.15')

import software.pando.crypto.nacl.*
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*
import java.util.*
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
import java.security.*
import java.nio.charset.*

def base64 = new Base64(3)

def key = base64.decode(args[0])
def value = StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(args[1], "")

println "Encrypting " + value

def keyPair = CryptoBox.keyPair();
def githubPublicKey = CryptoBox.publicKey(key)

def box = CryptoBox.encrypt(keyPair.getPrivate(), githubPublicKey, value)
    
def out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
box.writeTo(out);
out.flush();

def encryptedValue = new String(base64.encode(out.toByteArray()))

println encryptedValue
```

For example:

```
groovy encrypt.groovy 2Sg8iYjAxxmI2LvUXpJjkYrMxURPc8r+dB7TJyvvcCU= test
```

The problem is that the generated value is ignored when it is used to create a new [GitHub API secret](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-or-update-a-repository-secret). You attempt to create the secret, and the HTTP requests works ok, but the secret is empty when you use it in a workflow.

Secrets created from this Python script that generates encrypted values works fine however, so I know I am making the correct HTTP calls and using the correct keys to generate a GitHub secret:

```
from base64 import b64encode
from nacl import encoding, public
import sys

def encrypt(public_key: str, secret_value: str) -> str:
  """Encrypt a Unicode string using the public key."""
  public_key = public.PublicKey(public_key.encode("utf-8"), encoding.Base64Encoder())
  sealed_box = public.SealedBox(public_key)
  encrypted = sealed_box.encrypt(secret_value.encode("utf-8"))
  return b64encode(encrypted).decode("utf-8")
  
print(encrypt(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
```

What am I doing wrong with the Java (or Groovy) example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python code uses [sealed boxes](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/public-key_cryptography/sealed_boxes), the Java/Groovy code does not, so the two are not compatible.

Since the generated ciphertexts are not deterministic, a direct comparison is not possible. A reasonable test is to decrypt the ciphertexts of both codes using the *same* code.
The following Python code uses the posted code for encryption and then performs decryption with the supplemented code. This code will be used to test the Java code later:

```py
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from nacl import encoding, public

def encrypt(public_key: str, secret_value: str) -> str:
  """Encrypt a Unicode string using the public key."""
  public_key = public.PublicKey(public_key.encode("utf-8"), encoding.Base64Encoder())
  sealed_box = public.SealedBox(public_key)
  encrypted = sealed_box.encrypt(secret_value.encode("utf-8"))
  return b64encode(encrypted).decode("utf-8")

pkB64 = 'xBC9lTyWdE/6EObv5NjryMbIvrviOzzPA+5XyM0QcHE='
skB64 = '0b9867Pq6sEdnxYM1ZscOhiMpruKn1Xg3xxB+wUF5eI='

# Encryption
encrypted = encrypt(pkB64, 'test')

# Decryption
secret_key = public.PrivateKey(skB64.encode("utf-8"), encoding.Base64Encoder())
unseal_box = public.SealedBox(secret_key)
plaintext = unseal_box.decrypt(b64decode(encrypted))
print(plaintext.decode('utf-8')) # test
```

---

Sealed boxes don't seem to be supported by [salty-coffee](https://github.com/NeilMadden/salty-coffee) (at least I haven't found a way). Therefore, and because I don't know of any *pure* Java library that supports sealed boxes, I use [lazysodium](https://github.com/terl/lazysodium-java) (which is also a wrapper over the Libsodium library, though) to demonstrate the migration. For other libraries (even pure Java libraries, if there are any), this should be largely analogous:

```java
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.HexFormat;

import com.goterl.lazysodium.LazySodiumJava;
import com.goterl.lazysodium.SodiumJava;
import com.goterl.lazysodium.utils.Key;
import com.goterl.lazysodium.utils.KeyPair;

....

SodiumJava sodium = new SodiumJava();
LazySodiumJava lazySodium = new LazySodiumJava(sodium, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Key secretKey = Key.fromBase64String("0b9867Pq6sEdnxYM1ZscOhiMpruKn1Xg3xxB+wUF5eI=");
Key publicKey = Key.fromBase64String("xBC9lTyWdE/6EObv5NjryMbIvrviOzzPA+5XyM0QcHE=");

// Encryption
KeyPair keyPair = new KeyPair(publicKey, secretKey);
String ciphertext = lazySodium.cryptoBoxSealEasy("test", publicKey);
System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(HexFormat.of().parseHex(ciphertext)));

// Decryption
String decrypted = lazySodium.cryptoBoxSealOpenEasy(ciphertext, keyPair);
System.out.println(decrypted);
```

If a ciphertext generated with this code is used as ciphertext in the Python code, it can be successfully decrypted, which shows that the encryption of both codes is functionally identical.

---

**Edit:**

As an alternative to another library, salty-coffee can be extended to support sealed boxes.

If the sender uses a sealed box, basically the following happens:

1. first, an ephemeral key pair is generated: `ephemSK`, `ephemPK`.
2. let `PK` be the public key of the receiver. A 24 bytes nonce is determined as follows: `nonce = Blake2b(ephemPK || PK)`
3. an encryption is performed with *CryptoBox* using `ephemSK` as secret key, `PK` as public key and the previously generated `nonce`.
4. `CryptoBox` returns the concatenation of ciphertext and the 16 bytes MAC. `ephemPK` is prepended to the ciphertext. The concatenation of these 3 parts is the result of the sealed box.

salty-coffee provides all Libsodium functionalities needed for the implementation except Blake2b. For this you can use e.g. Bouncycastle.

A possible implmentation is:

```java
import software.pando.crypto.nacl.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.util.Base64;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.Blake2bDigest;

...

byte[] plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  
// Sender's secret key SK, receiver's public key PK 
byte[] SK = Base64.getDecoder().decode("0b9867Pq6sEdnxYM1ZscOhiMpruKn1Xg3xxB+wUF5eI=");
byte[] PK = Base64.getDecoder().decode("xBC9lTyWdE/6EObv5NjryMbIvrviOzzPA+5XyM0QcHE="); 

// Create an ephemeral keypair: ephemSK, ephemPK
KeyPair ephemKeyPair = CryptoBox.keyPair();
byte[] ephemSK_pkcs8 = ephemKeyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();
byte[] ephemPK_x509 = ephemKeyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();
byte[] ephemSK = getRawKey(ephemSK_pkcs8);
byte[] ephemPK = getRawKey(ephemPK_x509);

// Create the nonce = Blake2b(ephemeralPK || PK))
byte[] noncematerial = new byte[64];
System.arraycopy(ephemPK, 0, noncematerial, 0, ephemPK.length);
System.arraycopy(PK, 0, noncematerial, ephemPK.length, PK.length);  
byte[] nonce = new byte[24];
Blake2bDigest dig = new Blake2bDigest(null, nonce.length, null, null);
dig.update(noncematerial, 0, noncematerial.length);
dig.doFinal(nonce, 0);

// Encrypt with CryptoBox using ephemSK, PK and the nonce
CryptoBox cryptobox = CryptoBox.encrypt(CryptoBox.privateKey(ephemSK), CryptoBox.publicKey(PK), nonce, plaintext);
byte[] ciphertextMAC = cryptobox.getCiphertextWithTag();

// Prepend ephemPK
byte[] secretBoxSealed = new byte[ephemPK.length + ciphertextMAC.length];
System.arraycopy(ephemPK, 0, secretBoxSealed, 0, ephemPK.length);
System.arraycopy(ciphertextMAC, 0, secretBoxSealed, ephemPK.length, ciphertextMAC.length);
String secretBoxSealedB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretBoxSealed);
System.out.println(secretBoxSealedB64);
```

with:

```java
// The raw keys are the last 32 bytes in PKCS#8 and X.509 formatted keys respectively.
private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] key) {
    byte[] result = new byte[32];
    System.arraycopy(key, key.length - result.length, result, 0, result.length);
    return result;
}
```

A ciphertext created with this code can be successfully decrypted by the Python code above, proving the compatability.

Comment: This is indeed the case - GitHub will silently accept and ignore an encrypted secret that isn't created with sealed boxes. The docs simply say "Encrypt your secret using LibSodium", so I was hoping salted coffy would be enough. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a native Java solution here, and you must use native library wrappers.

Comment: @Phyxx - It's not that hard to extend the salty-coffee library to support sealed boxes. I have added in the *Edit* section of my answer a possible implementation for the encryption part whose generated ciphertexts can be successfully decrypted with the Python test code.

Comment: I would like to know the apis which can give me the public key and secret key. I am new to github action

Comment: @Kampassi - Please ask a new question (if you have not found a suitable answer on SO) with all the information required for the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, this answer helped me implement a pure Java version of Go's `nacl/box.SealAnonymous` using the salty-coffee library.